# Proguard returned with error code 1 - trying to use Proguard

Tags: java, android, performance, sdk, proguard

I am trying to use Proguard for the 1st time, I am getting this error, Can someone give me a hand pls. thanks

```
[2014-09-03 11:44:58 - P - Photos] Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
[2014-09-03 11:44:58 - P - Photos] java.io.FileNotFoundException: Photos\proguard\dump.txt (The system cannot find the path specified)
[2014-09-03 11:44:58 - P - Photos]  at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
[2014-09-03 11:44:58 - P - Photos]  at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
[2014-09-03 11:44:58 - P - Photos]  at java.io.FileReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
[2014-09-03 11:44:58 - P - Photos]  at proguard.FileWordReader.<init>(FileWordReader.java:39)
[2014-09-03 11:44:58 - P - Photos]  at proguard.ConfigurationParser.parseIncludeArgument(ConfigurationParser.java:217)
[2014-09-03 11:44:58 - P - Photos]  at proguard.ConfigurationParser.parse(ConfigurationParser.java:124)
[2014-09-03 11:44:58 - P - Photos]  at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:484)
```

Answer (score 1):

I discovered I had white spaces in my project name. So I renamed with no spaces and it worked